# How to properly transition after signing with FB to home screen without showing login screen first?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I created a social signin using FB with my app. Upon signing with FB it transitions back to login screen and then Home screen of my app. How do i make it after signing in with FB transition directly to Home screen and not login screen first before home screen.

Code showing connecting to FB:

```
    let parameters = ["fields":"id, email, first_name, last_name"]
    let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters, HTTPMethod: "GET")
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({(connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Facebook Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let id = result["id"] as? String else{
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        print("FacebookId connecting: \(id)")
        //connect to app server
        //passes user id and connects to back-end server
        self.connectToserver(id)
```

function after connecting to fb to my back-end:

```
private func connectToserver(id: String) {
        let endPoint: String = "*********"
        let params = ["id": id]

        let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: endPoint)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        do {
            request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            print(params)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }

        print("Facebook")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard let data = data where error == nil else {
                print("Error connecting: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse//HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    print("FaceBook post to server")
                    print("Response: \(response)")
                    // let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
                    let result = json as? [String: AnyObject]
                    print("Result: \(result)")
                    guard let token = result!["token"] else {
                        print("Error: \(error?.debugDescription)")
                        return
                    }

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(token, forKey: "token")

                    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.getHome()
                    //})

                }
                catch {
                    print("Error receiving data")
                }
            }
```

redirecting to Home screen:

```
private func getHome() {
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tableController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabController")

        let appledDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        //appledDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        appledDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tableController        
    }
```

Comment: If you want to get some help you have to post some code related to how you are using your navigation controller and your method for FB login

Comment: @Rajat i was editing my code. I just posted my code

Comment: On which controller you have implemented Login with Facebook ?

Comment: @Rajat the login controller called WelcomeHomeController

Comment: What you mentions seems counter intuitive. Because you want to validate FBLogin success/failure, you need to first land on the login screen and then decide to move to home screen if FBLogin is successful. If landing back on Login is absolutely not an option for you, you can move to a placeholder splash screen before opening the FB login and move to home or back to login based on success or failure respectively.